# Codingbat sameStarChar exercise

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with this codingbat exercise:

Returns true if for every `*` (star) in the string, if there are chars both immediately before and after the star, they are the same.

sameStarChar("xy*yzz") // true
sameStarChar("xy*zzz") // false
sameStarChar("*xa*az") // true

The right answer is:

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i - 1) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I wrote is:

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

        if (str.substring(i, i + 1) == "*" && str.substring(i - 1, i) != str.substring(i + 1, i + 2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the substring and charAt methods.

Comment: `String`s are objects. Don't compare objects with `==`, use `equals`

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: `String` is a **reference** and when you use `==` you are comparing that the two references are the same, not their contents.

Comment: BTW a String is substantially slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.charAt()` is easier to read and understand in this case.

Also, your substring solution should be more like

```
if (str.substring(i, i + 1).equals("*") && 
        !str.substring(i - 1, i).equals(str.substring(i + 1, i + 2))){
//etc.
}
```

Substring returns a string, and to compare the literal sting value you have to use the .equals() method.

Answer (score 2):

**Instructions:**

Returns true if for every '*' (star) in the string, if there are chars both immediately before and after the star, they are the same.

```
sameStarChar("xy*yzz") → true
sameStarChar("xy*zzz") → false
sameStarChar("*xa*az") → true
```

**Pseudocode**:

Loop over every character from 1 to length-1. If the character is an asterisk and the character before it is different from the one after, return false.  Otherwise if when you reach the end, return true.

**Code:**

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str){
  int len = str.length();
  for(int x = 1; x < len-1; x++){
    if (str.charAt(x) == '*' && str.charAt(x-1) != str.charAt(x+1)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Comments:**

It's a linear time O(n) operation.

Comment: I've now seen several times, that someone created a new variable for the length of the string in a codingbat-solution. Is there a deeper reason to it, instead of writing `for(int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++){`? Just curious, nice solution.

Comment: Why should sameStarChar(""star"xa"star"az") equal true?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I count the number of '*' and number of pairs that are matched and check if they both are equal and return true.

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  int count=0, noOfPairs=0;
  for(int i=1; i<str.length()-1;i++){
    if(str.charAt(i)=='*') count++;
    if(str.charAt(i)=='*' && str.charAt(i+1)==str.charAt(i-1)) noOfPairs++;
  }
  if(count==noOfPairs) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to look at...

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  
  if(str.length()==0) return true;
  if(str.length()==1 && str.contains("*")) return true;
  if(!str.contains("*")) return true;

  int i = 0;
  boolean result = false;
  while(i<str.length()-1){
    if(i!=0 &&  str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i-1) == str.charAt(i+1)){
      result = true;
    }else if(i!=0 && str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i-1) != str.charAt(i+1)){
      result = false;
    }else if(str.charAt(i) == '*'){
      result = true;
    }
    i++;
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A version which does not iterate over each individual character in the string by using indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  int i=0;
  int l=str.length();
  for(i=str.indexOf("*",i);i!=-1;i=str.indexOf("*",i+1))
  {
    if(i==0 || i==l-1)    //saves the program from accessing an out of bounds Index
    continue;
    else
    {
      if(str.charAt(i-1)!=str.charAt(i+1));
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your program does and how it does it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Normally, one would iterate over each individual character of the given string to check whether it is equal to "*". Instead of doing that, i use the IndexOf('x',z) to find the Index at which the character "*" occurs. As the method returns only the first occurrence of a character, i use the index of the previous occurrence+1  as the place from where the search should start next. The whole above logic is placed in a loop which terminates when there are no more "*" characters left .